# Resetting HTML <audio> loop with .keyup() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fairly new to jQuery and HTML, and I am attempting to write code that will play a few different sounds when certain keys are pressed. I've figured out how to play the sounds, but I need the loop to stop and reset when the key is released (i.e. so that a key could be pressed multiple times in rapid succession and the sound is started, stopped, and restarted along with each keydown). I think I need to maybe write a function or plugin for it, but am not sure how to go about it. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="sound/mpeg">
  <source src="sound.ogg" type="sound/ogg">
  <embed src="sound.mp3">
</audio>
```

and, jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("keydown", function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
            case 65:
                $("#sound").get(0).play();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

I've found lots of info using something like .setInterval and .currentTime to set the loop timer, but can't seem to get it to fit into my situation.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try a keyup handler

```
$(function() {
    var sound = $("#sound").get(0);
    $(document).on("keydown", function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
            case 65:
                sound.play();
                break;
        }
    }).on('keyup', function(){
        sound.stop();
    });
});
```